# pocket PC 2003 XML

Tags: .net, xml

Hello guys Im new in creating mobile applications in .NET.
And I have a problem with these codes:

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml(_xmlDataFile); -> here is the error

could somebody please tell me what are the possible reason why an error always occur. Im really wondering because this is the exact code that my professor used and he doesnt encounter any error on this part. Thanks in advance!

Comment: need to see the rest of the code, what is _xmlDataFile. Does that file exist?

Comment: private static string _xmlDataFile = @"Program Files\labExperiments\appointment.xml"; - the XML file is also already in "copy if newer"

Comment: what is the error that you get?

Comment: This is the error that I got - Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are passing in a string to `ReadXml()` which is not XML (it is a file name), you need to open a `FileStream` on the name first then pass that into `ReadXML()`.